# Modify or remove specific environment variables on every logout

Tags: debian, environment-variables, logout

Whenever a (graphical) logout occurs on Debian 11, I want to conditionally (e.g. `if $XDG_DEBUG == 1`, then ...) set or clear specific environment variables for the active user. The environment variables should be modified/removed on any terminal, which gets invoked by a later login of the user later on (e.g. `bash` and `zsh`) for `Gnome Desktop` and `Mate Desktop`.

**Important**: The environment variables should be get modified/deleted on every logout, so for the following sequence: Logout, Login, Logout again, they are modified/removed twice. There is no reboot involved.

The background is, that the Mate desktop sets specific environment variables, but they are not removed properly, when logging out. So when logging out from Mate desktop and then logging in using Gnome desktop, the set environment variables interfere with the Gnome desktop, resulting in situations, where specific applications cannot be started anymore. Even system applications will fail, because some environment variables are set improperly.

Thus, I want to make a cleanup-task, which removes specific environment variables. I tried several approaches, like with `systemd` but it all did not work out. Of course, it is important, that this script does not get killed on logout, before completed successfully. As already noted, it should be run on every logout, not only on shutdown/reboot.

*A solution which works for logging out from Gnome desktop AND Mate desktop would be even better, but it should at least work for logging out from Mate desktop. Any working solution would be ok for me.*

How to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried setting the start environment with a [systemd.environment-generator](https://man.archlinux.org/man/systemd.environment-generator.7) script. You can put this script in `/etc/systemd/user-environment-generators/` and it just has to output the *var=value* strings you want for the desktop you are in.

Comment: @meuh Isn't this only for starting a desktop session? I need a solution where environment variables are getting deleted on logging out of a desktop session.

Comment: Yes, it is only for the start, but perhaps if you can always force the starting environment, you don't need to worry about clearing up at the end, which seems to be difficult.